# Deserialize JSON get response using csharp

Tags: c#

Having some issues desearializing json get response from server. Final goal is to extract zoneid from json response...but currently, after the desearialization process is performed, obtained value is equal null. Any idea how I could tweak the code below in order to  achieve so....Thanks beforehand.

csharp code:

```
 public static void edgeCommunicationHandler(string locationURL)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
                          locationURL);
            // If required by the server, set the credentials.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            // The using block ensures the stream is automatically closed.
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                // Read the content.
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    
                // Display the content.
                Response userStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responseFromServer);

                
                Console.WriteLine("ZoneID: " + userStatus.zoneId);
                Console.WriteLine("User Status" + userStatus.resourceURL);
                           
            }

            // Close the response.
            response.Close();
        }



public class Response
        {
           
            public string zoneId { get; set; }
            public string resourceURL { get; set; }
        }
```

JSON File (validated using https://jsonlint.com/):

```
{
    "userList": {
        "resourceURL": "https://try-mec.etsi.org/sbxetyvtaz/location/v2/queries/users",
        "user": [{
            "accessPointId": "4g-macro-cell-6",
            "address": "10.100.0.1",
            "locationInfo": {
                "latitude": [
                    43.737373
                ],
                "longitude": [
                    7.418842
                ],
                "shape": 2,
                "timestamp": {
                    "nanoSeconds": 0,
                    "seconds": 1624887009
                }
            },
            "resourceURL": "https://try-mec.etsi.org/sbxetyvtaz/location/v2/queries/users?address=10.100.0.1",
            "timestamp": {
                "nanoSeconds": 0,
                "seconds": 1624887009
            },
            "zoneId": "zone03"
        }]
    }
}
```

**Output:**
Both variables are null

Comment: The `json` may be valid, but your class doesn't represent that `json`, it's not correct and is missing other classes needed in order to deserialize correctly.

Comment: @zaggler Hi zaggler, could you point me to any resources that might help me creating the class correctly? Thanks

Comment: [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) or [json2Csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) will be useful. Once you create the needed classes in order to deserialize correctly, if you're still having issues then make a new post and include all the details.

Comment: Hey man, I used json2Csharp per your recommendation. One last question if you don't mind. Do you happen to know how the syntax of printing zoneID would look like? I am struggling to find it in the doco...Thanks!!!!!

Comment: User is an array/collection, you would need to get it by index/name etc... Something like: `string userZoneIDOne = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseFromServer).userList.user[0].zoneId; `; not sure on your class/properties names etc... Also there are no checks in that code.

Comment: @zaggler Love you man... to the moon and back!!!!!! thanks for your time and help :)

P.S. it worked btw

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the object described by the JSON response is different to the structure of the response class.

The responseUrl is nested within an object called userList in the JSON.
zoneId has a multiplicity issue as well. It is part of the objects in the array called users which is part of userList.

You would need to define classes for UserList, LocationInfo, User and TimeStamp in order to map the structure of the JSON object to C# classes.